# Match all CSS selectors that have a certain property and value with RegEx

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds, regex-greedy

I have a feeling that what I'm trying to do is really easy, but I'm stuck with this for a while now so a little help would be much appreciated, here is an example of what I got:

```
.selector, .selector2 {
  color: #fff;  
  background: #f4c13b;
  opacity: 1;
}

.selector3:hover {
  color: red;
  opacity: 0;
  background: #f4c13b;
}

#selector4.class {
  background: #f4c13b;
  color: red;
}

@media (min-width:320px) {
  selector5 {
    opacity: 1;
    background: #f4c13b;
  }
}
```

Now, I want to match every selector that has `background: #f4c13b;`, so the capturing group will return: `.selector, .selector2` and `.selector3:hover` and `#selector4.class` and `selector5`.

Here is what I got so far: `/(.*) {[\S\s][^background]*background: #f4c13b;/gm`

Unfortunately, it only matches selectors that have `background: #f4c13b;` as a first property, so if there is something before `{` and `background: #f4c13b;` it would *not* match :(

Here is the basic idea behind this, every selector is on the new line, so I want to match and capture everything before `{` and then select everything before `background: #f4c13b;` and then everything before `}` so that I can extract the selectors from the first capturing group.

I am using the regexr.com to test the expressions and I'm guessing they are using *JavaScript flavored RegEx*. A little help and explanation would be very, very much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Do you need a solution specifically using regex? What is your use case? I think it might be easier to just parse the CSS fully, with something that can understand CSS3 selectors, and even compressed CSS, then iterate over all the selectors …

Comment: I think you need to tell us which language you are using.  In Java (or even JavaScript), you would be repeatedly matching a pattern and extracting out selectors into some sort of data structure.

Comment: By the way, `[^background]` doesn't mean match any string except for `background`.  Instead, it says to match any single _character_ except for `b,a,c,k,g,r,o,u,n,d`.

Comment: It doesn't have to be RegEx, I proposed it because it's the only tool I know that could do the job. I'm using the regexr.com to extract the selectors in the  _List_ panel where I type `$1,` and that's how I get all selectors which I then copy and paste where I need. Thank you for a quick reply, I really appreciate it!

Comment: You can try using this: `(.*)? {.*?background: #f4c13b;` ... if you are using a tool like Notepad++ you can keep applying it.

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing, probably because the dot matches any character except new lines and the `background` property is on the new line. I changed it to `/(.*)? {[\S\s]*?background: #f4c13b;/igm` and it works, at least I think so... I'll test with few more examples and I'll let ya'll know :) Thank you so far, this community is amazing!

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work :'( RegEx matches a selector that is **after** the selector I want. It also matches any first selector that is in the css file. Any ideas why this is happening @TimBiegeleisen ? Thank you very much!

Comment: Not sure what is happening, `.*?background` should match up until the _first_ occurrence only.  You should really tell us what tool/language you plan to use here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use this regex : `/([.#]?[\w, .:]+?)(?= \{[^}]+?background: #f4c13b;[^}]+?\}\s*)/g`

**Explanation:**

```
/                               : regex delimiter
    (                           : start group 1
        [.#]?                   : optional dot or hash
        [\w, .:]+?              : 1 or more alphanum, comma, space, dot, semicolumn, not greedy
    )                           : end group 1
    (?=                         : lookahead
        \{                      : open curly bracket
        [^}]+                   : 1 or more any char that is not close curly bracket
        background: #f4c13b;    : literally
        [^}]+?                  : 1 or more any char that is not close curly bracket, not greedy
        \}                      : close curly bracket
        \s*                     : 0 or more "spaces" including linebreak
    )                           : end lookahead
/g                              : regex delimiter, global flag
```

**In action:**

```js
var x = `.selector, .selector2 {
  color: #fff;  
  background: #f4c13b;
  opacity: 1;
}

.selector3 {
  color: red;
  opacity: 0;
  background: #ffffff;
}

.selector3:hover {
  color: red;
  opacity: 0;
  background: #f4c13b;
}

#selector4 {
  color: red;
  opacity: 0;
  background: #f4c13b;
}

selector5 {
  color: red;
  opacity: 0;
  background: #f4c13b;
}
@media (min-width:320px) {
  selector6 {
    opacity: 1;
    background: #f4c13b;
  }
}`;
var r = x.match(/([.#]?[\w, .:]+?)(?= \{[^}]+?background: #f4c13b;[^}]+?\}\s*)/g);
console.log(r);
```

Comment: Thank you very much that works well in most cases but I should've mentioned while asking the question that a selector can sometimes start with a `#selector` or even without anything at all `div` so this code will fail with ID and html element selectors. One more thing, this code will also fail if there is a `@media { ...` before it, is there a possibility to make this code more bullet-proof by taking those cases into account? Thanks a bunch again!

Comment: @pbe:See my edit.It works for `.`, `#` or nothing. For `@media`, what do you mean by "before it"? Please, edit your question with complete test cases

Comment: @pbe:It seems OK now. Doesn't it?

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you very much on behalf of all the front-end _coders_ :)